# counting strings in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data. The `Status` column shows cycles which are moving from *FORWARD* to *REVERSE* for 1 completion of cycle. Next cycle starts when *FORWARD* appears again. I want to count them.

```
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
| Index |   X   | Z(mm)  |   FT   | Status  |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
|   484 |   0.5 |  0.053 |  0.212 | FORWARD |
|   485 |   0.5 |  0.053 |  0.214 | FORWARD |
|   486 |   0.5 |  0.055 |  0.214 | FORWARD |
|   ... |       |        |        |         |
|   584 |   1.0 |  -0.07 |  0.137 | ARRET   |
|   585 |   1.0 |  -0.07 |  0.135 | ARRET   |
|   586 |   1.0 | -0.069 |  0.135 | ARRET   |
|   587 |  0.51 |  0.056 |  0.213 | REVERSE |
|   588 |  0.51 |  0.056 |  0.214 | REVERSE |
|   589 |  0.51 |  0.056 |  0.214 | REVERSE |
|   ... |       |        |        |         |
|   641 | -0.07 |  0.137 |  0.202 | ARRET   |
|   642 |   1.0 |  -0.07 |  0.135 | ARRET   |
|   643 |   1.0 | -0.069 |  0.135 | ARRET   |
|   ... |       |        |        |         |
|   658 |   0.0 | -0.018 | -0.202 | FORWARD |
|   659 |   0.0 | -0.019 | -0.201 | FORWARD |
|   660 |   0.0 | -0.019 | -0.201 | FORWARD |
|   ... |       |        |        |         |
|   827 |  0.51 |  0.033 |  0.214 | REVERSE |
|   828 |  0.51 |  0.033 |  0.214 | REVERSE |
|   829 |  0.51 |  0.033 |  0.215 | REVERSE |
+-------+-------+--------+--------+---------+
```

I want this

```
+-------+------+--------+--------+---------+---+
| Index |  X   | Z(mm)  |   FT   | Status  | N |
+-------+------+--------+--------+---------+---+
|   484 |  0.5 |  0.053 |  0.212 | FORWARD | 1 |
|   485 |  0.5 |  0.053 |  0.214 | FORWARD | 1 |
|   486 |  0.5 |  0.055 |  0.214 | FORWARD | 1 |
|   ... |      |        |        |         |   |
|   587 | 0.51 |  0.056 |  0.213 | REVERSE | 1 |
|   588 | 0.51 |  0.056 |  0.214 | REVERSE | 1 |
|   589 | 0.51 |  0.056 |  0.214 | REVERSE | 1 |
|   ... |      |        |        |         |   |
|   658 |  0.0 | -0.018 | -0.202 | FORWARD | 2 |
|   659 |  0.0 | -0.019 | -0.201 | FORWARD | 2 |
|   660 |  0.0 | -0.019 | -0.201 | FORWARD | 2 |
|   ... |      |        |        |         |   |
|   827 | 0.51 |  0.033 |  0.214 | REVERSE | 2 |
|   828 | 0.51 |  0.033 |  0.214 | REVERSE | 2 |
|   829 | 0.51 |  0.033 |  0.215 | REVERSE | 2 |
|   ... |      |        |        |         |   |
|  9220 |  1.0 | -0.141 |  0.118 | ARRET   | 2 |
|  9221 | 1.01 |  -0.14 |  0.118 | ARRET   | 2 |
|  9222 | 1.01 |  -0.14 |  0.117 | ARRET   | 2 |
+-------+------+--------+--------+---------+---+
```

#data in column `Status` is a series
`ARRET` is in between which I want to count as well with the previous cycle or with next cycle. both are ok

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Series.shift` to detect the changes, then count the booleans with `cumsum`:

```
fw = df["Status"].eq("FORWARD")
rv = df["Status"].shift().eq("REVERSE")
df["N"] = (fw & rv).cumsum().add(1)
```

```
    Index     X  Z(mm)     FT   Status  N
0     484  0.50  0.053  0.212  FORWARD  1
1     485  0.50  0.053  0.214  FORWARD  1
2     486  0.50  0.055  0.214  FORWARD  1
3     587  0.51  0.056  0.213  REVERSE  1
4     588  0.51  0.056  0.214  REVERSE  1
5     589  0.51  0.056  0.214  REVERSE  1
6     658  0.00 -0.018 -0.202  FORWARD  2
7     659  0.00 -0.019 -0.201  FORWARD  2
8     660  0.00 -0.019 -0.201  FORWARD  2
9     827  0.51  0.033  0.214  REVERSE  2
10    828  0.51  0.033  0.214  REVERSE  2
11    829  0.51  0.033  0.215  REVERSE  2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is putting just 1 in the column N for all values and not increasing

Comment: Please edit your example dataframe to reproduce your actual data and so that my solutions fails, because based on the data right now, my solutions works.

Comment: ok I have edited the data. Sorry for the confusion